# internally URL change via htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a technical challenge with a peice of code in .httasse (apache/php server)

I wana redirect this URL:

Clean URL: example.com/archives.html/2014-2-10

So I use this code:

```
RewriteRule ^(archives\.html)/([0-9-]+)/?$ /$1/?option=com_arcives&date=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

.............
It works but It dose not work correctly.

I used R flag so The Clean URL must changes only internally...but it is not happen!

before click: example.com/archives.html/2014-2-10

after click auto change to: example.com/archives.html?option=com_arcives&date=$2014-2-10

I want to stay it only internally...

who know whats my problem?

I'm using wampserver on windows(local host)

Comment: Is this some CMS/PHP framework?

Answer (score 1):

The `R` flags makes it redirect, you should not use that flag.